# Alternative for [0-9] in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query use to return all values with two digits back to back:

```
Select WHERE (DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%[0-9][0-9]%')
```

But it no longer works.  Is there a workaround using postgresql?  Something possible while still using "ilike" or non regex.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is regular expressions:

```
where description ~ '[0-9][0-9]'
```

You can also use `similar to`, but the regular expression is so simple.

Comment: Thanks.  Would where description ~ '[0-9][0-9] PF %' replace Where DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%[0-9] PF %'?  With a space before and after PF.

Comment: No.  For `~`, you don't use the `%` at the beginning and end.

Comment: What could I use instead of %?

Comment: @ZJAY . . . You don't need anything.  By default, `~` matches at any point in the string, rather than the entire string.

Comment: @ZJAY Note that this is still using a "regex" (you wrote - "*or non regex*")